# Unable to patch businessPhones of Entra External ID user, Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing an application to update users in Entra's "Azure AD for Customers" (now in Preview) by calling Microsoft Graph. The application is granted with permissions "User.ReadWrite.All".

When I send a patch request to update businessPhones of a specific user e.g. {"businessPhones":["+41761234567"]}, I always receive a response code 403 with the message "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation", even if the businessPhones parameter is just an empty collection, i.e. {"businessPhones":[]}. It also does not matter whether the businessPhones is empty or not.

I have used Microsoft Graph Explorer to test / reproduce this and it seems that:

- It is not a problem when I post (instead of patch) the request with businessPhones.
- It is not a problem I patch a user in a regular Azure AD repository.
- It is a problem when I patch a user in an Azure AD for Customers repository.

I have tried to modify permissions using Microsoft Graph Explorer e.g. by adding Directory.ReadWrite.All but this also didn't result in any improvement.

There are a number of similar issues on StackOverflow but in my opinion this issue behaves slightly different and I can only reproduce this for Azure AD for Customers users (the issue does not occur for regular Azure AD users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have user named **`SriCustomer`** in my Azure AD for Customers repository:

[image]

When I tried to update **businessPhones** property of this user using below PATCH request, I got **same error** as you even after granting `User.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/11475d17-d370-4ecc-9bec-xxxxxxxxx/
{
    "businessPhones": [
        "+41761234567"
    ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, `businessPhones` and `mobilePhone` are [**sensitive
> properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-beta#who-can-perform-sensitive-actions) that requires additional permissions or roles to update.
>
> In delegated scenarios, updating sensitive properties require extra
> permission named **Directory.AccessAsUser.All**.

As [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) works with delegated authentication, I added `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission like below:

[image]

When I ran the **PATCH** request again after granting consent to above permission, I got **response** like this:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/11475d17-d370-4ecc-9bec-xxxxxxxxx/
{
    "businessPhones": [
        "+41761234567"
    ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where `businessPhones`  property updated successfully like below:

[image]

Similarly, you can also update  `mobilePhone` property after granting consent to **Directory.AccessAsUser.All** permission.

**Reference:**
[Update user - Microsoft Graph beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Thank you @Sridevi. This does resolve the issue when trying to patch sensitive properties such as `mobilePhone` and `businessPhones` using **delegated permissions**. Unfortunately, the application that I am developing is running as a deamon and is using **application-level** permissions. I haven't found the proper permission to add for this specific case.

Comment: In **app-only** scenarios, you need to assign Directory roles like `User Administrator` to the service principal in order to update sensitive properties.

Comment: I just discovered this as well. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To be more precise (also see [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-beta#who-can-perform-sensitive-actions): The role of **User Administrator** is not sufficient. To update sensitive properties such as `mobilePhone` and `businessPhone`, the service principal requires the role of **Privileged Authentication Administrator** or **Global Administrator**.

Answer (score 0):

What I remember, some phone numbers need to encode `+` in PATCH request

```
{
  "businessPhones":[
    "%2B41761234567"
  ]
}
```

Another tip: To update some properties on `User` you need `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission.

Comment: Thanks @user2250152 but neither tip helped and I am still receiving 403 - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. I also noticed that I get the same response when I try to update the mobilePhone property of a user.